# R functions, access to parameter names

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have the following code:

```
fn <- 'George'
mn <- 'Walker'
ln <- 'Bush'
f <- function(...) { print(list(...)) }
```

When I call it, it produces the following output:

```
f(fn,mn,ln)
  [[1]]
  [1] "George"

  [[2]]
  [1] "Walker"

  [[3]]
  [1] "Bush"
```

Suppose I wanted something similar to this (note the parameter names):

```
fn:George
mn:Walker
ln:Bush
```

Question: I know how to get the VALUES of the arguments inside a function. How do I get the NAMES of the arguments inside the function?

Thanks, CC.

Comment: You should put a `?names` somewhere but I do not know where.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
f <- function(...) {
     nm1 <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
     val <- list(...)
   cat(paste(nm1, val, sep=":", collapse="\n"),'\n') }
f(fn,mn,ln)
#fn:George
#mn:Walker
#ln:Bush
```